# Acknowledging the message on wildcard-address does not acknowledge the same message on the qualified-address

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

- Spring JMSListener listens at `/queue/app/*`
- The message is actually produced at `/queue/app/XXX` and so also available at the wildcard-address ( `/queue/app/*` ) to consume
- Once the processing is successful at the listener, the message is acknowledged at the wildcard-address ( `/queue/app/*` ), but not the original address ( `/queue/app/XXX` ).

My concern is that the message will retain the storage till expiry.

How can we solve this?

### Usecase

My setup is as follows -

**Service A**

Subscribes to `/queue/A/*`

Publishes to `/queue/B/tenantId`

**Service B with TenantID = 1**

Subscribes to `/queue/B/1`

Publishes to `/queue/A/1`

**Service B with TenantID = 2**

Subscribes to `/queue/B/2`

Publishes to `/queue/A/2`

Basically, **Service A** sends message to **Service B** via the independent-queues ( `/queue/B/tenantId` ) for different tenants. The idea behind separate queues for each tenant is to eliminate inter-tenant competition within the queue. Also, there will be multiple instances of **Service B** running for each tenant. Now once the **Service B** is done with the message-processing, it will publish the response-message back to **Service A** on the tenant-specific queue ( `/queue/A/tenantId` ). The idea here is to have the logical-isolation among tenant response-messages. Finally, the reason to use wildcard-address in **Service A** is because we can not have a dedicated consumer for each tenant in **Service A** and we plan to share it across tenants.

### broker-00.xml

```
 <address-settings>
        <address-setting match="/queue/#">
            <default-address-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-address-routing-type>
            <default-queue-routing-type>ANYCAST</default-queue-routing-type>
        </address-setting>
        <address-setting match="/topic/#">
            <default-address-routing-type>MULTICAST</default-address-routing-type>
            <default-queue-routing-type>MULTICAST</default-queue-routing-type>
        </address-setting>


        <address-setting match="#">
            <auto-delete-queues>false</auto-delete-queues>
            <auto-delete-jms-queues>false</auto-delete-jms-queues>
            <auto-delete-jms-topics>false</auto-delete-jms-topics>
            <auto-delete-addresses>false</auto-delete-addresses>
            
            <max-delivery-attempts>15</max-delivery-attempts>


            <expiry-delay>86400000</expiry-delay>
            <redelivery-delay>3000</redelivery-delay>
            <redelivery-delay-multiplier>1</redelivery-delay-multiplier>
            <redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>0.15</redelivery-collision-avoidance-factor>
            <max-redelivery-delay>50000</max-redelivery-delay>
            <default-consumer-window-size>0</default-consumer-window-size>
        </address-setting>
    </address-settings>
    <wildcard-addresses>
        <routing-enabled>true</routing-enabled>
        <delimiter>/</delimiter>
        <any-words>#</any-words>
        <single-word>*</single-word>
    </wildcard-addresses>
```

Comment: What protocol(s) are you using?

Comment: Are you using `anycastPrefix=/queue/` on your acceptor?

Comment: I am using STOMP protocol from Service B and CORE protocol from Service A. I am not using anycastPrefix, instead I am using address-setting for /queue/# to create ANYCAST queues.

Comment: Why did you select anycast? Does multicast not fit with your use-case? Also, please add relevant config to your question (e.g. address-settings you'd added, etc.).

Comment: @JustinBertram I have added the details as requested.  used anycast as I wanted a point-point communication. Also, I wanted only one pod of the Service-A to consume the message from the queue. In the case of multicast, my understanding is that if I have replicas of Service-A, all of them will receive the same message and I want to avoid that. Basically I want guaranteed and at most once delivery of message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the expected behavior. Remember, it's a wildcard *address*, not a wildcard *consumer*. Messages sent to any address matching the wildcard address will be routed to the queues bound to the wildcard address and those messages are acknowledged independently of the messages routed to the particular address' queues where they were originally sent.

If you don't want messages to accumulate in any of queues then simply remove the queues and just have the address. An address without any queues is a perfectly valid configuration.

Comment: thanks for your response. With STOMP SEND and SUBSCRIBE, artemis automatically creates the anycast queue. How can I configure to only create address instead? Also, is the concept of persistence bypassed with the suggested setup?  FYI, I choose messages to be persistent on message-level based on certain use cases.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want multicast semantics, but it's hard to answer your question without a full explanation of your use-case. Please modify the original question and elaborate. I'm not sure what you mean about persistence with this setup. Everything I've discussed so far is unrelated to persistence.

Comment: I have added the use case as requested. About persistence, as you mentioned the messages will not be accumulated, I thought it means the messages will not be durable. Please elaborate on what you meant by messages not getting accumulated.